# Django HttpResponseRedirect can not found url

Tags: django

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('horizon.views',
url(r'home/$', 'user_home', name='user_home'),
url(r'register/$', Register.as_view(), name='register'),
url(r'success/$', Success.as_view(), name='success')
)
```

And this my views.py:

```
 class Register(forms.ModalFormView):
    template_name = 'auth/test.html'
    form_class = CreateUser
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

 class Success(generic.TemplateView):
     template_name = 'auth/success.html'
```

I try to use:

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect('success')
```

or

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))
```

but it is can not render the success.html. Who can tell me why ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: are you supposed to have that trailing `)` in your `views.py`?

Comment: There is no error to display, it can not redirect the "success" url...  In views.py class Register(forms.ModalFormView):
        template_name = 'auth/test.html'
        form_class = CreateUser
        success_url = reverse_lazy('login') It redirect to "login" url ..

Comment: What part of your code is calling `return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')` ?

Comment: Jump to the "class Success" in views.py , according to urls.py

Comment: Sorry I understand that - I meant what view should be redirecting to the success page? e.g. `Register` redirects to `login`. What redirects to `success`?

Comment: en. I have a view named "class Success(generic.TemplateView):"redirects to "success".

Answer (score 1):

Please post the exact error you are getting.

When doing your `HttpResponseRedirect` it's best not to hardcode URLs like '/success/'.

Instead do this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


....
    # Here 'success' is the URL name you have given.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))
```

This way, if you change the success URL (not that you should..) it will automatically update throughout your app rather than having to go back and change all your hardcoded values.

Read more about it in the Django [Reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) documentation.

Comment: I follow you advice, but it not good. Both "return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))" and return  "HttpResponseRedirect('success')", does not effective. Thank you.